# How do I resync itunes to my music library?

Tags: itunes

I keep my music in an external hard drive which was disconnected while iTunes was on. I reconnected the drive and restarted iTunes but it still can't find the music. Would prefer not to fix manually, there are over 3,000 albums in that directory.

Comment: switch to a better music player that doesnt try to manage music for you. itunes will delete files if it doesnt think they should be there

Comment: Ok, I would switch to a different player in a heartbeat as I absolutely hate iTunes but haven't found anything that will let me manage my ipod. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

1. Open iTunes on your PC/Mac
2. Select File in the top left corner from the menu bar.
3. Choose Add to Library… and select the missing media.
4. You will be able to see your songs and playlists in the Music section.